# Change part of the url using url redirect

Tags: java, css, regex, web-services, jsp

I have an issue where the image paths in css files need to be changed dynamically. Currently the image links are like `url(../../image/image.png)` in some css files. In others the links are like `url(../image/image.png)`.

I am packing all the css files into one file using `pack:tag` and as a result, the `../../image/image.png` links get broken when accessed from the packed css file as from the packed css file, the correct path becomes `../image/image.png`.

I was told that the way to fix the issue is to use url redirect and tuckey but I am unsure about the process. I added the filter in web.xml, but what rule should I add in the urlredirect.xml ? Currently it reads:

```
<rule> <from>.*/behavior/(.*)</from> <to type="forward">/css/$1</to> </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd get around that by using absolute references rather than relative. So use `url(/yourfolder/image/image.png)`.